# Eclipse Plugin Zend Studio

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, zend-studio

I'm going to write a plugin with Eclipse Mars for my Zend Studio 10.4 
I know that the Zend Studio is based on Eclipse. Is there anything to condsider? Versions, Configurations and so on? Does somebody have links to good Eclipse-Plugin-Tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answert to my own question by my selfe. Yes it work!!  Very nice. But if you've build the .jar-file ( export ) you have to do some steps to use the own written plugin in your Zend Studio. Here is the link : 
[enter link description here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=50293&p=123018#p123018)

I hope, that i can help some other developers with this post!!